# React-Emotion - Animating a div with EmotionJS

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I need some help with animating my div.
I am using [Emotion-JS for React](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion).

I dont think the animation is working.
Below is my component.

[image: Edit jl857l6vo3]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind the tips of the *@Powell_v2* answer above, it is right!

However for your case you don't even need to use animation and keyframes. Just use `transition`.

**transition-duration: 10s;**

**transition-property: width;**

````
        <div
          className={css`
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 10vh;
            width: ${this.state.open ? "80vw" : "10vw"};
            height: 8vh;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 999;
            border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
            transition-duration: 10s;
            transition-property: width;
          `}
        />
    ```
````

Comment: Yes , that kind of does it. Thanks

Comment: How is this different from the `keyframes` defined in the emotionJS docs?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the provided example, a couple of things should be adjusted:

- It's recommended to use `@emotion/core` with React ([ref in docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/install))
- `css` function doesn't return a computed class name string - styles should be set via `css` prop ([ref in docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#string-styles))
- It looks like you got @keyframes wrong - [read up on it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to obtain better understanding.

Hope that helps you.